# Thread Interrupts. Can someone explain me the output to understand interrupts better?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, interrupted-exception

I am able to understand Threads and interrupts. I was trying to map the underlying concepts learnt from Oracle tutorial to understand concept of interrupts better. I developed this example and tried hard to understand the output as how interrupts are playing a role here. I just did not understand. So my notion was to ask someone to help me understand the output of this program which will clear me more about underlying functionality of interrupts.

```
public class ThreadSleepTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        MyRunnable myRunnable = new MyRunnable();
        Thread one = new Thread(myRunnable);
        one.setName("Fred");
        Thread two = new Thread(myRunnable);
        two.setName("Lucy");
        Thread three = new Thread(myRunnable);
        three.setName("Ricky");
        one.start();
        two.start();
        three.start();
        //Thread.sleep(1000);
        one.interrupt();
     }    
}

class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        for (int x = 1; x < 4; x++) {
            System.out.println("Run by: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                System.out.println("Exception occured");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Do something");
    }
}
```

Here is the output from my console.

```
Run by: Lucy
Run by: Fred
Run by: Ricky
Exception occured
Run by: Fred
Run by: Fred
Run by: Lucy
Run by: Ricky
Do something
Run by: Lucy
Run by: Ricky
Do something
Do something
```

Comment: read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Comment: I have read it and i understand but still output is confusing.

Comment: Confusing why? What did you expect? Why?

Comment: What @EJP suggested is worth an upvote!

Comment: @KedarMhaswade i am finding the concept just confusing so inital issues. I am sure you must have found the concurrency tricky as well.

Comment: @benz Concurrency is very tricky. I believe what EJP is suggesting is if the program's output was confusing to you, then find out what kind of output would have been less confusing.

Comment: @KedarMhaswade i did not understand that part. Actually,thats true, but concepts will be clearer if understand complex issues. But yes concurrency is definitely tricky.

Comment: @benz You haven't answered my question.

Comment: @EJP. I was finding concept of sleep and interrupts confusing. I made this example and was not able to understand the output keeping concepts of interrupts in mind and i wanted someone to help clarifying the output which would have led me to understand concept of interrupts more better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Once a thread is interrupted, it is basically taken out of operation as per my understanding.

No, your understanding is incorrect. Once a thread is interrupted, it is up to the programmer who wrote the `run` method to decide what to do about it.

Thread termination is entirely up to the programmer, as the JVM doesn't actually know what resources and locks you may need to clear up when you terminate the thread. This is the reason why the methods `stop()` and `suspend()` in `Thread` have been deprecated. They are not safe.

So when a thread is interrupted, if you are in a method that throws an `InterruptedException`, you have to react to this exception and finish whatever it is you are doing, and if you are in the middle of your own stuff, you have to check the `interrupted()` status of the current thread from time to time, and if an interrupt occured, finish up what you are doing.

Here is what you chose to do when your thread is interrupted:

```
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            System.out.println("Exception occured");
        }
```

In your `catch` clause, you are merely printing the fact that the exception occured. You are not actually doing anything towards termination of the thread. Therefore, it will not be terminated. You'll go out of the catch clause, and continue with the next iteration of your loop.

`Thread.sleep()` by convention clears the interrupted flag when it throws the `InterruptedException`. So in the next iteration, the thread is no longer "interrupted", and `sleep()` does not throw the exception again.

Answer (score 1):

Interrupting a thread means signaling it to stop doing what it currently does.

Most I/O and locking operations will interrupt when the thread the run on is interrupted and an `InterruptedException` is raised in that thread (however, not all operations do so, for example see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#acquireUninterruptibly()).

The code is then able to process the exception in any way he/she sees fit. After the `InterruptedException` is raised, the interrupt signal is consumed, the thread can continue to do anything. In your example, the `Thread.sleep()` call finishes earlier, the InterruptedException is thrown and a message is logged. After that, the thread continues the `for` loop. Of course, the thread can be later interrupted.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Java Concurrency in Practice (JCiP), page 138 gives a fairly good explanation of what might be happening. There are a few things that you can note:

- The main thread creates and starts 3 threads named: Fred, Lucy, Ricky. Let's just consider the thread named Fred, which is assigned to the variable `one` (There are better ways of doing this e.g. the [CountdownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html)).
- Fred, after being scheduled to run is immediately put to sleep by your code. The method `Thread.sleep` is a well-designed *blocking call*. This means that it can be interrupted by sending an interrupt. This is exactly what main thread tries to do: request an interruption in whatever activity  thread `one` is doing or not doing (since it's just sleeping in this case). The `main` thread does that by simply calling the `interrupt()` method on `one`. Note that this is perceived only as a 'friendly request' by the thread being interrupted.
- In the case when you see the output 'Exception occurred', the (sleeping) interrupted thread acknowledges the interrupt and like it is documented, an InterruptedException is thrown. This exception is caught by `one` and the message 'Exception occurred' is printed on the stdout. Thus, the main thread *has succeeded in interrupting what `one` was doing*.
- Other threads do their tasks without interruption (that's why you see the other print statements).

Answer (score 0):

If you interrupt a thread, the next or current time you sleep or wait in this thread its going to throw an InterruptedException. BUT the interrupted state is cleared with this. If your Thread is interrupted, you should terminate it in the near future.